# figuring out what counts as an instruction in java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what constitutes an instruction in java code. In class lecture that I attended professor mentioned 7 things that can be constituted as instruction but. I am having trouble making out what.

assignment, access of array, return statement, addition multiplication subtraction,..

Here is a example code she gave out:

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
while ( i < 3 ) {
    sum += A[ i ];
    i++;
}
```

she says there are total of 18 instructions in this java code but I only count 15. Could you guys clarify why this is.

Comment: Compile the code, the run `javap -c <classname>`

Comment: I think you mean "statement" as there is no standard meaning for an instruction of Java.  You can have an instruction in bytes code or machine code which is an indivisible block of code.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "instruction", e.g. `int sum = 0` is really a combination of `int sum` and `sum = 0`. Is that 2 instructions? Well, `int sum` *declares* a variable, so it is technically an instruction to the compiler, but it doesn't generate any code. `sum = 0` does generate 2 bytecodes (load `0`, store in `sum`), but it is only one statement, and one instruction (assignment). So, to repeat, it depends on definition of "instruction", and is a rather meaningless thing to count, in my opinion.

Comment: she said the first two lines were counted as 2 instructions, and because of the loop structure there were 5 instructions that were executed 3 times inside the loop. and I believe one for accessing the loop. I was confused and asked her what she meant by it but she just said she would upload a powerpoint which it never came.

Comment: @JCharles if she would be strict she´d say this. `sum += A[ i ]` is an assignment, addition an array acces. `i++` is an assignment, an addition and a return, which would result in 6 "instructions". She might have skipped the return in `i++` for what she calls "instructions". In addition 2+3*5 would be 17 ;).

Comment: @JCharles If she counts the statements inside the `while-loop` as five instructions, then she miss two comparissions in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something is missed in the explanation what count as `instruction`

Taking this schema there would be twenty.

```
1) int sum = 0;       // 1 assignment
2) int i = 0;         // 1 assignment
3) while ( i < 3 ) {  // 1 comparison
4)     sum += A[ i ]; // 1 array access, 1 addition, 1 assignment --> sum = sum + A[i]
5)     i++;           // 1 addition, 1 assignment --> i = i + 1;
6) }
```

The lines 3-5 are executed three times.